# Ubuntu 13.10: Upgrade interrupted because of openjdk-7

Tags: apt, upgrade, java, openjdk

I was running an apt-get upgrade (not version upgrade, just normal), when I got this message:

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    icedtea-7-jre-jamvm : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (=
>   7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1)
>
> openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (=
>   7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1)
>
> openjdk-7-jre-lib : Breaks: openjdk-7-jre-headless (< 7u45-2.4.3-1)
>
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

I then run as recommended "apt-get install -f" and here is the output:

> Preparing to replace openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3
>   (using
>   .../openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
>
> Unpacking replacement openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 ... dpkg: error
>   processing
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb
>   (--unpack):
>
> trying to overwrite shared '/etc/java-7-openjdk/sound.properties',
>   which is different from other instances of package
>   openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
>
> Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

How can I fix this error?
Thanks

UPDATE:

The 1st time, I ran the command, there was no output. Now, running it again, I get:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of
>
> openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64:  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64 depends on
>
> openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.10.1).
>
> dpkg: error processing openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (--remove):
>
> dependency problems - not removing Errors were encountered while
>
> processing:  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove previously installed `openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64` package,

```
sudo dpkg -r openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
```

Then try,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried that. No error message came after the 1st command, but the same error as before came after the 2nd

Comment: Post the output of 1st command?